# Can I loop a tree diagram?

Tags: d3.js

I need to show a data structure which is a hierarchical one's, except for one value I highlight on following image:

[image]

The two nodes *Pages.app* should be merged. I perform this structure with d3's tree layout. Can I merge this node with same layout, or should I find a graph one?

Comment: You can't use the tree layout for this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Ok, can you recommend me a d3s' layout type to use for looped graph?

Comment: The force layout is the only one that's applicable for this type of graph.